# Intersection volume between two hemispheres

Tags: math, computational-geometry, volume

Suppose I have two hemispheres in 3D space with centers and radii c1, r1 and c2, r2. The planes that define the bases of the hemispheres have coefficients (A1, B1, C1, D1) and (A2, B2, C2, D2). I am interested in calculating the intersecting volume if these two hemispheres clash.

I developed an approximate method to do this, which breaks down the two hemispheres into equally spaced points in a common coordinate system. Then, I estimate the volume by calculating the number of points that are present in both the hemispheres. The smaller I make the spacing, the more accurate the answer. But reducing the spacing increases the runtimes too. I am looking to use a analytical way to obtain faster and more accurate answers.

I know that for two intersecting spheres, the intersecting volume is given by the equation shown in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html and the volume of two intersecting hemispheres is some fraction of this. I have tried to use the angle between the base planes to provide some indication of the fraction but have failed to do so.

I asked this question on math.stackexchange but got no replies. Hoping to get some ideas here.

Thanks

Comment: Not directly related to programming

Comment: [Math.se] is really the better place for this question. If they cannot come up with an analytic solution, there might be none. In this case, triangulate the hemispheres (including the bottom plane), perform a mesh Boolean operation, and calculate the volume of the result.

Comment: Do the spheres intersect on their spherical cap, or can it be any way ?

Comment: If you want an exact, analytical solution, it will be terrible. Because the intersection volume is a bispherical lens which is trimmed by two arbitrary planes, leading to a complex geometry and the need to resort to spherical trigonometry. The case of sphere-hemisphere seems more tractable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little hope to solve this analytically.

Consider the intersection of the base planes and set a Z axis on it. Then choose an origin and define the axis X and Y in these planes. In general they won't be orthogonal (by a change of coordinates Y' = Y - α X, you can make them so).

Compute the plane that contains the intersection of the sphere surfaces (a small circle), let Zp = aX + bY + c, and determine the sign corresponding to either sphere.

With the help of this plane, you can split the bispherical lens in two plane-spherical ones, which you process separately.

For given (X, Y), the range of Z is given by

Min(Zp, Z0 - √(R0² - (X - X0)² - (Y - Y0)²) to Min(Zp, Z0 + √((R0² - (X - X0)² - (Y - Y0)²)

for one of the lens, and this range can be empty.
Finally, you have to compute a double integral of these Z ranges *in the first quadrant* of XY (as the axes are skewed, you need a correction, but the Jacobian is constant). The inner integral is certainly feasible.

For the outer integral, if necessary you can resort to numerical integration. As it is unidimensional, the cost should not be too high.